# encode and decode javascript objects to and from the string

Tags: javascript

I want to use Javascript object as a key in the hashmap. In order to do this, I have to convert this Javascript object into the string. There also has to be a way to decode the object back from this string.

What is the best way of doing this?

So far I have found two ways of converting it. Using [JQuery Params method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) and JSON.stringify.

Thanks.

Comment: JSON: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON. Assuming you are working with simple objects only.

Comment: ^ I have listed my research and asked for the better option whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON) is what you need:

- Object to string

  ```
  JSON.stringify(obj);
  ```
- String to object

  ```
  JSON.parse(obj);
  ```

Or you could use ES6 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in order to be able to directly use objects as keys, but currently browser support is small. Also note that different objects will be associated with different values, even if they look like the same:

```
var m = new Map(),
    obj1 = {}, obj2 = {};
m.set(obj1, 'foo');
m.set(obj2, 'bar');
m.get(obj1); // 'foo'
m.get(obj2); // 'bar'
```